# How do I print a variable in java with an index added to the variable name?

Tags: java, indexing

This is what I want to do in python, but I don't know how to do it in Java. I have an object called LogRecord and I have different instances of it saved as record1, record2, record3 etc. But I want to make a for loop that will print all of them out by incrementing i by 1 each time. Sorry if this sounds stupid, just don't know how to do it. Read my example below and hopefully you can understand my problem

```
LogRecord record1 = new LogRecord (1, "20200301");
LogRecord record2 = new LogRecord (2, "20200302");

for (int i = 0; i < logIndex; i++) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print(record1.logIndex + "  ");
        System.out.print(record1.date + ", ");
```

Instead of printing record1, I want it to print record1 then record2 and so on. Tried to simplify it a bit. Sorry if this question is stupid and ignore my amateur code thanks :)

Comment: what about storing records in an array / list / iterable / whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple variables, you should use either a list or an array of `LogRecords` and access individual elements with `.get`. For instance:

```java
List<LogRecord> records = new ArrayList<LogRecord>();
records.add(new LogRecord(1, "20200301"));
records.add(new LogRecord(2, "20200302"));
for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print(records.get(i).logIndex + "  ");
    System.out.print(records.get(i).date + ", ");
}
```

This code can be further simplified by using a for-each loop to iterate through all the elements:

```java
for (LogRecord record : records) {
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print(record.logIndex + "  ");
    System.out.print(record.date + ", ");
}
```